# security of rdbms

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I am designing the human resource database for company ABC. and i want to deploy a relational model for the company database. Referring to the above scenario, how do you prevent users from changing the values in the primary table that results in orphaned records in a related table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest looking at Foreign Keys: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key